# How do I trigger an observer when column_name changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

I want to trigger an email if a new system admin is granted. I have set up a user observer. I want to trigger the email when admin column_name changes to true.

More important this change will happen through the console and not through the UI.

Here is what I have:

```
def after_update(user)
  if user.admin_changed?
    AdminMailer.new_system_administrator(user).deliver
   end
end
```

finally using dirty? function to trigger the email

Comment: Glad you accepted an answer, can we see your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the is dirty? function on Db column to trigger the email